# Can I _.isMatch multiple values?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am expecting the below code to return Chris Davis and Mike Trout. It only returns Mike Trout. Is it not possible to match on multiple values? Please keep in mind I need to match on over 30 values eventually. I tried using indexOf as well which did not scale well.

```
jsonData:
{ matchup: '@ LAA', name: 'Chris Davis' }
{ matchup: 'vs BAL', name: 'Mike Trout' }


jsonData.forEach(function (element, i) {
  if (_.isMatch(jsonData[i], {matchup: 'vs BAL' || 'vs LAA'}) == true) {
    console.log(jsonData[i].name)
  };
})
```

Comment: `matchup: 'vs BAL' || '@ LAA'` means just `matchup: 'vs BAL'` as strings are truthy.

Comment: I cleaned up my code a little. Can you explain your comment further? If they are truthy should they not be logged to console?

Comment: What I'm saying is that this makes little sense `'vs BAL' || 'vs LAA'` because the right side will never be the result.

Comment: I see. Because the first one is truthy the second never gets evaluated. I get it now. How would you accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `||` in the statement like:

```
if (_.isMatch(jsonData[i], {matchup: 'vs BAL'}) || _.isMatch(jsonData[i], {matchup: 'vs LAA'))
```

Or more dynamically, you could store the values you want and iterate:

```
var matches = ['vs BAL', 'vs LAA']
var isMatch = matches.some(function(match) {
  return _.isMatch(jsonData[i], {matchup: match})
})

if (isMatch) {
  console.log(jsonData[i].name)
}
```

Comment: Trying this out now. Thanks for the answer. I'll let you knw if it works!